# Tracing the question commented

Tags: discussion, comments

Suppose I commented on a question asked. After I logout and login how to find the question for which I commented?  Is there any link.  **(NOTE)** Since I have not answered, the link to the question is not specified in the Answered section. Also if anyone has not commented back on the question, I have to fetch the HISTORY and then find the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the recently updated [Activity tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155654/chid?tab=activity) in your profile. It lists all* of your activity on the current site, and there is a filter to show only comments. From there you can find a link to the comment that you made, which will take you back to the question.

<sub>*All publicly available information, for the most part</sub>